# Git - how to push untracked (ignored) file in repo automatically

Tags: git

I have a react bundle that take it to long to compile and i want to do it on local PC, them push it to prod with rewrite old one.

This bundle is ignored by git (using `.gitignore`) for developing.

I can't make bundle on production server, because i need to stop server, because some user request maybe downloading it.

Is there a way to always push ignored file to git?

Comment: Can you remove it from `.gitignore`, `git add`, `git push` and then add it again so no differences are pushed/pulled?

Comment: By hand -yes, but how to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force ignored files to be added to your local repository (and subsequently push them) via `git add -f filename`.